# OSX & GIT -- Connect to remote repository using just a ppk file

Tags: git, macos, ssh, pem

Just switched to OSX, and I am having trouble connecting to a remote repository using the information provided.  I had no trouble in the past connecting using Windows, and I am new to OSX and am a little lost.

I need to connect via SSH and I've been provided with a zip containing a PPK file and another file that has no file extension.  I've read that I need to add this to my user folder's `.ssh` directory.

I cannot seem to view anything inside of the .ssh folder -- When I `ls ~/.ssh`, it only shows the directory itself.  When I try to rename my PPK files to "id_rsa" and "id_rsa.ppk", and `mv id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, it says that `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is not a directory.  I need help.  Can someone give me a beginners walkthrough of how to do this process?

Answer (score 0):

PPK is a PuTTY file. To convert it to an OpenSSH key pair, which OS X uses, you would need to install PuTTY. You can install it with the homebrew mac package manager. Details can be [found here](https://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux).

But first see if the other file is already an OpenSSH file. Run `file other-file` to see if it's ascii text. If so, check the first line. If you see `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, rename it id_rsa, chmod 600, and move it to `~/.ssh`. If it's a DSA private key, do the same but rename it id_dsa.

If the private key is encrypted, you would need a password to use it. The OS X keychain can remember it for you after it is first entered.

Comment: The other file is a OpenSSH file.  I have verified that it is a RSA private key.  I have renamed it, chmod'ed it 600, and moved it to ~/.ssh.  What is the next step?  I try to clone the repository but it asks me for a password that I do not have still.

Comment: The corresponding public key might not be installed on the remote repo. You can test with `ssh -v you@remoterepo.com`, `ssh -vv you@remoterepo.com`, or `ssh -vvv you@remoterepo.com` for varying levels of debug info.